# "ReliefMap" and "ContourMap" unable to download error

Tags: graphics, curated-data, geography

This question may be closed as "too localized". I post in the event other users have had this error and resolved it.

The problem: inability to use "ReliefMap" or "ContourMap" options for `GeoBackground` or `GeoStyling` despite:

- contacting Wolfram Technical support and

  - clean starting
  - re-downloading 10.2 and reinstalling (clean as per Wolfram)
  - following various other instructions

System:

> ```
> {
>   {"10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)"},
>   {"10.2.0.0 (5353456, 2015070702)"}
> }
> ```

OS: Windows 8.1

Code:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["ReliefMap", Opacity[0.8]],   
 Polygon[CountryData["UnitedStates"]]}, 
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"Image", CountryData["UnitedStates", "Flag"]}], 
 GeoRangePadding -> None]
```

The following graphics illustrate the error and workaround. 
This error occurs for all examples in documentation as well as user defined attempts. Technical support have not found a solution but have been extremely helpful (for which I am grateful).

I accept if this is closed for being too localized.

[image]

[image]

A work around:
[image]

A code example:

```
GeoGraphics[Entity["Country", "France"], 
 GeoServer -> {"http://www.staremapy.cz/naturalearth/`1`/`2`/`3`.png",
    "Projection" -> "Equirectangular", "ZoomShift" -> -1, 
   "AxisOrientation" -> {1, 1}}, GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular"]
```

Comment: No problem with Mma v10.2 on OS 10.10.4

Comment: You write "Technical support have found a solution"; did you mean to write "Technical support have *not* found a solution"?

Comment: Could you post code rather than pictures?

Comment: @MarcoB I am sorry, As this did not relate to a coding issue but a failure of in built examples and user code  I posted pictures to show the errors. I agree I should have posted a small sample to allow copy and run.

Comment: @m_goldberg yes technical support did not find  a solution. Apologies for this omission. I found the workaround through documentation of Geoservers.

Comment: @m_goldberg I have corrected

Answer (score 5):

As workarounds, I think I would change the following, one at a time:

1. increase time out, `GeoServer` sub-option, `"GlobalTimeout"`
2. increase the number of retries, `GeoServer` sub-option, `"ConnectionRetryCount"`
3. decrease zoom level, `GeoZoomLevel -> 7 (* 6 *)`
4. use another tile server

`"GlobalTimeout"` defaults to 30 seconds, so I would start off by doubling it. `"ConnectionRetryCount"` defaults to 1 additional attempt, so if increasing the time out doesn't work, I would increase this to 3. Reducing your `GeoZoomLevel` from 8 to 7 or even 6 would also help reduce the amount of information the server sends, increasing your likely hood of getting something back.

The biggest change here is the number of retries, as every time a tile download succeeds, it is cached. So, partial successes will begin to add up.

Lastly, change tile servers. Here are several I use in my testing:

```
"http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/`1`/`2`/`3`.png"
"http://www.staremapy.cz/naturalearth/`1`/`2`/`3`.png"
```

For some reason, though, I have not kept the default settings for most of them. I will work on listing those.

Comment: thank you for this helpful answer. I will try when I get a chance. I will accept if it resolves issue.

Comment: I have tried the suboptions with no success. "StreetMap" works without a problem. Even server "http://www.staremapy.cz/naturalearth/`1`/`2`/`3`.png" has now stopped working. I do not think I am making the connection with the geoserver that provides the data and do not know how to proceed further. Thank you very much for the suboption and alternative servers.

Comment: Ok. Testing time. Have you tried this on a fresh kernel? If so, run `Import@StringTemplate[
   "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/`1`/`2`/`3`.png"][8, 45, 42]` for me please. You should get an image. Finally, start pulling the tiles using `GeoGraphics` starting at `GeoZoomLevel -> 1` and work up to 5 or 6. At what point does it stop working?

Comment: I will do when I can. Thank you very much for digging down I appreciate it. There will be a delay till I get to test. Apologies for that.

Comment: not a worry. Do what you can, when you can.

Comment: The command in fresh kernel failed: ->"The request to URL http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/1/2/3.png  was not \
successful. The server returned the HTTP status code 404 ("Not \
Found")."

Comment: `Import@StringTemplate[
   "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/`1`/`2`/`3`.png"][8, 45, 42]` returns an image

Comment: see previous comments. `GeoGraphics[Polygon[Entity["Country", "Italy"]], GeoZoomLevel -> 1, 
 GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap"]` yields error:" Unable to download data for ranges {{36.1215,47.611},{6.03655,19.1116}} and zoom level 1 from the geo server ReliefMap. >>"

Comment: I'm at a loss. I'll point a dev at this and see if they can come with something.

Comment: thanks...it is probably something on my system or perhaps because I am from antipodes...it is perplexing that other features work and has persisted after clean reinstall after new download...appreciate the follow up sincerely...midnight here and am at work with no time at present...thanks again :)

Comment: @ubpdqn after speaking with the developer on this, we're at a loss without further diagnoses. So, if you would contact `support@wolfram.com`, and we'll see what can be done.

Comment: thank you...that is where I started and no success yet...thank you again!